# Creating Specific Button Using Pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to CSS/HTML. Using pure CSS (no image overlay), how can I create a button like this (Please see attachment). The side triangle and tick mark appears when the button is active.

[Tick Mark and side banner on button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxZgD.png)

Thank You

Comment: Try to.google checkbox button and custom checkbox button

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```css
button {
    border: 4px solid #FFCC00;
    height: 100px;
    width: 140px;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 8%;
}
.corner {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #FFCC00;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.tick{
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    left: -1px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span class="corner"></span>
  <span class="tick">&#10004</span>
  ON
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a million. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score -2):

```
enter code here
```

```css
.btn {
   display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 4px;
   background-color: transparent;
   padding: 14px 36px;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: pointer;
   font-size: 1rem;
   transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-blue {
   border: 1px solid #007bff;
   color: #007bff;
}
.btn-green {
   border: 1px solid #28a745;
   color: #28a745;
}
.btn-red {
   border: 1px solid #dc3545;
   color: #dc3545;
}
.btn-grey {
   border: 1px solid #6c757d;
   color: #6c757d;
}

/* Change bg-color and text-color on mouse over  */
.btn-blue:hover {
   background-color: #007bff;
   color: white;
}
.btn-green:hover {
   background-color: #28a745;
   color: white;
}
.btn-red:hover {
   background-color: #dc3545;
   color: white;
}
.btn-grey:hover {
   background-color: #6c757d;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-blue">Blue</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-green">Green</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-red">Red</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-grey">Grey</button>
```

[CSS Styling Buttons](http://parrot-tutorial.com/CSS3/buttons.html)

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question. It just shows how to style a button. The main element in OP's question is the 'tick' mark in the top left corner of the button, which this solution doesn't provide